# Can a Windows UWP application connect to a websocket server, receive data from it, and display the data?

Tags: python, c#, uwp

This is my first real question on Stackoverflow.
I'm currently trying to implement an existing websocket server into my UWP (C# or C++) app. The server is running from my laptop and is receiving screenshot data. I want to send this screenshot data to my UWP app, and then display it there. I also would want audio. Kind of like a remote desktop situation. Is this possible, and if so can someone explain how this would work?

Here is my python code for the current screenshot sending method. It is by no means perfect and is very slow.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import socket
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pickle
from mss import mss
import struct
from time import time
from windowcapture import WindowCapture
# Client Side Initialization
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))
bounding_box = {'top': 100, 'left':0, 'width':852, 'height':480}

sct = mss()



# Change the working directory to the folder this script is in.
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

#not used atm
# initialize the WindowCapture class
# wincap = WindowCapture('FL Studio 20')

loop_time = time()
while(True):
    sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
    cv2.imshow('screen', np.array(sct_img))
    # get an updated image of the game
    #screenshot = wincap.get_screenshot()

    #cv.imshow('Computer Vision', screenshot)

    # debug the loop rate
    print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
    loop_time = time()

    #send client data
    frame = np.array(sct_img)
    data = pickle.dumps(frame)

    #send message length first
    message_size = struct.pack("L", len(data))

    #then data
    clientsocket.sendall(message_size + data)

    # press 'q' with the output window focused to exit.
    # waits 1 ms every loop to process key presses
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break

print('Done.')
quit()
```

And here is the server side code:

```
import pickle
import socket
import struct

import cv2

HOST = ''
PORT = 8089

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print('Socket bind complete')
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn, addr = s.accept()

data = b'' ### CHANGED
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") ### CHANGED

while True:

    # Retrieve message size
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)

    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0] ### CHANGED

    # Retrieve all data based on message size
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)

    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]

    # Extract frame
    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

    # Display
    cv2.imshow('Capture Server Test', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, what you're asking for is possible, but you're asking many questions in one and I don't see a way forward to helping your ask.  If you can limit your post to one question (how do I connect from my websocket client to server?), then that is actionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deciding to transfer stuff over the internet is a big step. This involves port forwarding, a good client/server setup and the actual code. [Some examples from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples) got me started to set up a TCP connection.

If your goal is to simply transfer your own data, TCP might work. Perhaps other protocols are better suited for you, if you need livestreams or just audio and video.

In general, this is too much to explain in a single answer, so I suggest you research on the following key things which will guide you towards a solid connection:

1. If you want this to work remotely, from another network to your home network, you will need to port-forward. [Here is some guide for it by a fantastic guy.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTLDsEuQlYc) This will allow your packages to go through your router without being blocked. And please, when something does not seem to work, try your firewall and/or try to [demilitarize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) your server/PC.
2. Think of how you want your computers to communicate theoretically. This is dependent on your computer science knowledge, but in general it works best to give both devices a specific role: one acts as a client, and the other as a server. To allow networking and stuff (portforwarding) to act as expected, the server should be listening to packets send by the client, to which the server reacts upon. This way, only the server needs to port-forward and the client can contact the server from anywhere. The client sends requests, on which the server responds.
3. When you have your plan, work it out! This may seem big, and wowie, but [the examples from Microsoft for C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) helped me out greatly. You only have to change some IP stuff to make it work in your environment, but the real core works just fine. I doubt however if it is suitable for your scenario, as I do not know if you want to send arbitrary packets or full streams. It seems like the latter, so you might want to check out other code.

As I mentioned earlier, this is quite global, but so is your question. Start from the beginning, ask more precise questions and you will get there. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into all the things and work it out more.